# Spring Application Beans Not Found Exception

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm using the following application context file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http:/www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http:/www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="helloWorld" class="helloworld.api.impl.HelloWorldImpl" />
</beans>
```

When I'm reading the file,
I'm getting the exception,

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 8 in XML document from file [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 68; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 68; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 14 more
```

I'm using spring 4.0 and I'm able to access the spring beans xsd through my network browser.

Comment: verify that spring is in your classpath (the whole thing core, context, etc)

Comment: Yeah Spring is my classpath

Comment: Can you list the jars name for us?

Comment: Make sure the correct spring version on your claspath and that you aren't mixing spring versions. Also it is recommended to use a versionless xsd so instead of `spring-beans-4.0.xsd` use `spring=beans.xsd`. It will automatically use the most recent xsd available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is missing configuration metadata;

Change your schema namespace below

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
```

Reference [Spring 4.0 Configuration metadata](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-metadata)

Comment: @wekselva, Same Error? Could u update new stack trace?

Comment: CycDemo I've made a mistake, 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http:/www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http:/www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">
instead it should be
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the error logs, The actual issue is not with the xml file but with the jars.

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 68; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

Make sure you have added all the required jars into your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try this declaration instead, as far as I understand the version is not required.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

Also with spring 4 you can use annotations

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    @Bean
    MessageService mockMessageService() {
        return new MessageService() {
            public String getMessage() {
              return "Hello World!";
            }
        };
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = 
          new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
      MessagePrinter printer = context.getBean(MessagePrinter.class);
      printer.printMessage();
  }
}
```

More at this [link](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/#quick-start)